# Bookmarklet to see hidden select

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet  to fill out a form but there is hidden selects that I am unable to see. The webpage works with a dropdown for Yes or No. if No is selected nothing happens if Yes is selected then a new select appears. Now if I run the bookmarklet below it will change the first select to Yes and then the next select does not appear or has information put into as far as I can tell.

```
javascript:(
function(){document.getElementsByTagName('Select')[1].value = 0;
document.getElementsByTagName('Select')[2].value = 4;
})();
```

Is there a way to refresh the page with out resetting everything to have the new select appear or is there a way to force hidden selects to appear even if there conditions are not met. Also as far as I can tell the hidden select and corresponding HTML items do not exist until the first select is changed to a yes. If I just had ('Select')[3].value = 4 with out changing the first select then it would skip over the hidden select and put information into the next visible.

Edit 06/04/2020 I don't know if I should repost this question or not but after playing with jquery and doing a little reading I was able to get my code below to work if I had previously changed the select manually and changed back. It does not work if the page had not been manually altered first.

```
javascript:(function(){$("select:eq(1)").val(0).change();})();
```

I'm still new but would appreciate a book or website that I should look into learning this stuff. I feel like there is more then just HTML, Javascript and jquery that I need to know in order to properly manipulate webpages.

Thanks.

Comment: Logically changing the value of an input will not generate normal events that are generated by user interactions.  If you need those, you have to do it logically as well.

Comment: is there a way to change the value of an input logically through a bookmarklet?

Comment: Provide the link and I'll take a look - it's possible to raise events to simulate having changed the selection.

Comment: unfortunately I can not provide a link to the website and I don't know much about HTML and programming websites. I do know that a previous coworker was able to jquerify a similar page and use var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); evt.initEvent("change", false, true);

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
javascript:(function(){
$("select:eq(1)").click().val(0).change();})();
```

It is currently in Jquery but it might be possible to be in Javascript.
I had to select the select within the webpage first using click then change the value then I used the change function. Hopefully this helps someone in the future or myself when I forget what I run into the same problem again.